# How do you configure prometheus.yml file to collect Prometheus metrics in a jax-rs application?

Tags: java, rest, api, prometheus

```
static Counter requests = 
        Counter
            .build()
            .name("count")
            .help("Total requests.")
            .register();



static Counter failedRequests = 
        Counter
            .build()
            .name("requests_failed_total")
            .help("Total failed requests.")
            .register();
```

I am using this code in jax-rs api. I want to integrate end point of metrics in api, also wants to configure prometheus for api calling counts.

Comment: show us your code. what you've done so far